# Make [macos-sierra] the canonical Sierra tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are two tags for macOS Sierra on the main site:

- [macos-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra) (749)
- [osx-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-sierra) (30)

The former reflects Apple’s decision to rename their OS with this version; the latter is consistent with the other formerly-OS X tags on the site.

I propose making [macos-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra) the canonical tag, and creating a synonym for the other tag.

(Although it’s small enough to retag manually, it’s the sort of tag I can see being repeatedly resurrected based on the other macOS/OS X version tags.)

Comment: The [tag:osx-sierra] seems to have non-trivial amount of off topic questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

alexwlchan is correct. Furthermore, the tag [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) should be made a synonym for a new tag [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) which is consistent with the official brand name, macOS. Apple updated the tradename (brand name) of the flagship operating system for Apple desktop and laptop computers.