# Rename [osx] to [macos]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

With the release of Sierra, [Apple has renamed their "OS X" operating system to "macOS"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326164), most likely to fit in with the other [Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) derivatives, iOS, tvOS, and watchOS.

In that spirit, [osx-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-sierra) [has already been renamed/retagged to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343481) [macos-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra) (although not synonymized).

Can we do the same for [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos), and make the former a synonym of the latter?

Comment: Related: [Talking about macOS and OS X with the new naming scheme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326164/424903). As that states, MacOS is only relevant for Sierra and beyond, anything prior is still OSX.

Comment: @Gimby Then what do you propose we call the operating system in general, without a version attached? What's the Mac equivalent to just "Windows" or "Ubuntu"? As of Sierra, `[osx]` seems to no longer apply.

Comment: Renaming this sounds like a job for Steve

Comment: MacOS sounds like the worst breakfast cereal ever.

Comment: "Change your app's name. Not that big of a deal. –Steve"

Comment: Mac OS X was for the most part a completely different operating system from the versions of Mac OS that preceded it.  The GUI was similar, but OS X is a BSD derivative, wereas Mac OS 9 and preceding were all-proprietary.  Apple made a big deal at the time about how OS X was revolutionary.  That would be a worthwhile distinction to capture via tags, but I'm uncertain whether it actually is captured in practice, or whether it ever was intended to be.

Comment: Only concern is with the confusion with [tag:macros] without the capitalization.

Comment: I've always had a slight issue with "osx": OSX was an IBM product, not at all related (AFAIK) to Apple's OS X.

Comment: So, when and how will we decide what to do?

Comment: @Raphael I suppose we gotta bother a mod about this and ask them whether they see the votes as enough of a community consensus...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per community sentiment, I've renamed [osx] to [macos] and created a synonym pointing from the former to the latter. This should complete the request.

Comment: Is there enough sentiment to also do this to [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym)

Comment: Oh now I understand why I just got the [macos bronze badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7525/macos?userid=1983854). I did not understand where it came from.

Answer (score 57):

Macintosh operating system names in recent history ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_operating_systems)):

- Mac OS (1997–2001)
- Mac OS X (2001–2012)
- OS X (2012–2016)
- macOS (2016–present)

Except for those ~4 years where "Mac" was omitted from the official name, it has always been some variation on "Mac OS".

I think changing the name to reflect the current "macOS" does not seem unreasonable.

The difference between versions names "OS X" and "macOS" is no more significant than the usual changes between releases. For more-specific version related questions, a more-specific tag like [macos-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra) should be used.

Comment: Question, since I do not know (and was not able to easily look it up): Did Apple actually officially announce the addition of the "X" to the name in 2001 or the drop of the "Mac" from the name in 2012 or did it just happen? I know they did with the change to macOS, but if they did not in previous times, then it may actually be worth going through with the rename.

Comment: @DavidB Wikipedia says the first OS X version was originally marketed as simply "version 10" (X being the roman numeral for 10, and it's supposed to be read as ["Mac OS 10"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/whats-the-proper-way-to-pronounce-mac-os-x)). All version numbers since have been 10.# . As for the drop of Mac, I didn't even realize the had done so until I made this answer, so I don't think it was really announced.

Comment: @david There was definitely an official announcement of the "Mac OS X" name. In fact, though, it was first used for [Mac OS X Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Server_1.0), which was basically a derivative of the NeXT/OpenStep OS that Apple had just acquired (by purchasing NeXT) and has little in common with the Mac OS X client that was released a couple of years later. They just shared the same name. As Alexander said, the "X" means and was intended to be pronounced "10", since this was the next major version after Mac OS 9. Big deal made about this at the Macworld Expo launch.

Comment: The dropping of "Mac" from "OS X" happened around the Lion (10.7)/Mountain Lion (10.8) time frame, and was never officially announced. It just kind of happened, and people started to take notice. Apple wasn't terribly consistent in whether the "Mac" was there when referring to Lion, but in Mountain Lion, the announcement and the OS's UI itself drops the "Mac" entirely, just using "OS X". See also: http://www.theverge.com/2012/2/16/2802281/apple-officially-renames-mac-os-x-to-os-x-drops-the-mac

Answer (score 6):

We currently even have [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) ← [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos). This synonym *definitely* has to go.

Whether we should have [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) ← [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) then is a good question; I for one don't have a position on that.

One can also ask of questions for obsolete versions should not be deleted, unless they still apply and can be retagged. But that is a larger issue for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Synonyms are not like symlinks; they work both ways. And for good reason IMHO: (Mac) OS X has always been a Mac OS, while for some time the current Mac OS was called "OS X". A problem only arises when you want to imply a specific version with the simple tag, which is probably not a good idea anyway.

Same with code names, btw. Big cats, places, mountain ranges etc. are nice for personifying software but not very helpful otherwise.

Comment: @RJVB Not quite. Only the main tag is shown. If you tag something [tag:macos], it'll wear [tag:osx] later. The only tag description you can access is the one of the main tag. Which means, you can not tag a question about the new macOS properly: these were *never* called OS X.

Comment: Isn't this currently backwards? [tag:macos] takes me to [tag:osx]. The reverse ought to be the case, clearly — no?

Comment: Actually, [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) has these tags done right, why doesn't SO?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius That's my point, yes.

Comment: Why on earth does the [macos] -> [osx] synonym "got to go"? They're the same freaking thing.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of a camelCase name is something Apple will probably regret a bit down the road, probably for the same reason it makes my eyes bleed when I see it outside of a programming context... Unless there's a secret plan to relegate the whole Mac line to dedicated workstations for turning out iDevice apps of course.

Anyway, replying to Siguza's question

> Then what do you propose we call the operating system in general, without a version attached?

That depends a bit on how general you want this to be, and also in what context you're asking (e.g. labels in/for progamming code or for precompiled binaries of your applications). The general name for the underlying operating system is Darwin, but that is officially the Unixy basis without the GUI layers.

If you want something more specific to Macs you could indeed use "macos" rather than "darwin", though with Apple's recent decision to use macOS as a distinguishing name makes the all-lowercase version ambiguous. Maybe "mac_os" to indicate it applies to all versions of the Mac OS?

You can also adopt the position that Macs are only set apart by their operating system, which was probably true always (was a PPC Mac running Linux ever any different from, say, and IBM PowerPC workstation running Linux?). And that means you could just use "mac". Of course that ignores the existence of Hackintoshes, but that distinction should be moot anyway.

FWIW, the Qt guys now use macOS throughout to align with Apple's whim. I cannot condone that because it implies that everyone should be running the latest Mac OS version.

Note also that Apple have been using MACOS and simply MAC for conditional coding purposes for a long time, allowing constructs like

```
#if QT_MACOS_PLATFORM_SDK_EQUAL_OR_ABOVE(__MAC_10_11)
```

Comment: *"Unless there's a secret plan to relegate the whole Mac line to dedicated workstations for turning out iDevice apps of course."* Oh, is that a secret? When I first saw it, it was obvious that the "macOS" name was chosen for synergy with "iOS" and "tvOS".

Comment: They certainly don't yet make it obvious that Macs are no longer those fantastic general-purpose computers for the general public as they were always made out to be. So yeah, if at some point in a near future they'll be selling Macs only to registered iOS/tvOS/watchOS developers that's still a secret. ;)