# Rename [macos] to [mac-os] to avoid confusion

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

I should say that I'm not a subscriber to the [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) tag and it's actually the first time I notice this tag. That being said, it looks very odd to me and could be easily mistaken for [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) at first glance. I wonder why it's written like this instead of [mac-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-os). Is there a reason for that?

I realize that *although it's sometimes referred to as **Mac OS**,* according to Apple, it's written **macOS** but since tags can't use uppercase letters, I suggest changing it to [mac-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-os).

**Notes:**

- Looks like it was [renamed recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360412) (relatively speaking) so perhaps it was just a quick decision *(deciding that "macos" is close enough to "macOS")*.
- There are other related *smaller* tags that depend on it (e.g., [macos-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-sierra), [macos-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-carbon)).

Comment: BTW, Mac OS refers to "Classic" (versions of Mac before X). The alternate/old name for macOS is Mac OS X.

Comment: Hmm, IDK. It just feels awkward written `macos` and can be mistaken for `macros` (which is what happened to me and inspired this question). Also, looks like [I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348077/rename-osx-to-macos/360412#comment466824_348077) who thought of that.

Comment: I don't really think how awkward it feels to you is really a reason for change. Also, unless it can be shown to have actually caused problems, it's still just a concern.

Comment: That's fair enough, I guess :)

Comment: Here are two examples were [macos] seems to have been mistaken for [macros]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52561182/4284627 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/52765380/4284627

Comment: @Donald Alternative theory: both of those askers were using Macs, and misunderstood the purpose of tags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The official product name is "macOS", with no spaces (or hyphens).

Thus, the tag is named accordingly.

I don't see any "confusion".